# How to query multiple symbols in a single AlphaVantage API call

Tags: alpha-vantage

I have an AlphaVantage (AV) API query that's working fine for a single asset's symbol, but when I add a second symbol, it only pulls data for the last of the two symbols.

This is what I'm running, and it only returns data for 'LRC':

**AV API Query**

```
url = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query"
 
params = {
   "function": "CRYPTO_INTRADAY",
   "symbol": ["UNI", "LRC"],
   "market": "USD",
   "interval": "15min",
   "outputsize": "full",
   "apikey": "ALPHAVANTAGE_AUTH",
   }
 
r = requests.get(url, params=params)
data = r.json()
 
print(data)
```

The only documentation I've been able to find is several years old, and haven't seen anything on their site addressing multiple symbol queries, so if anyone knows of any updates, I'd greatly appreciate input.

Thx

dsx

Comment: I too am curious if this is possible yet.